# Update a php variable within an array

Tags: php

I'm not sure how to describe this, so sorry if the title isn't correct for this question.

I have a file with a bunch of metaboxes but i'm trying to reduce the duplicate entries. So what I'm trying to do is create a variable containing an array which creates the metabox, then trying to update a variable within this array when I call it later on.

The example below i'm trying to update the `$title` but have no idea how to achieve this or what it's called to google a solution?

```
<?php
$metabox = array(
        'name' => "{$title}",
        'id'   => "column_content",
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'raw'  => false,
        'options' => array(
            'textarea_rows' => 3,
            'teeny'         => true,
            'media_buttons' => false,
        ),
    );

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'page_builder', 
    'title'      => 'Metabox Example',
    'fields'     => array(
        // Output the above array here:
        $metabox,

     ),
);
```

**Update**

I'm not sure I completely explained how I would like to achive this, I wanted to update the `$title` for the `$metabox` within the `$meta_boxes` array()

```
<?php
$metabox = array(
        'name' => "{$title}",
        'id'   => "column_content",
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'raw'  => false,
        'options' => array(
            'textarea_rows' => 3,
            'teeny'         => true,
            'media_buttons' => false,
        ),
    );

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'page_builder', 
    'title'      => 'Metabox Example',
    'fields'     => array(
        // Output the above array here and update the title on the fly:
        $title = 'NEW TITLE';
        $metabox,

     ),
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update the `$title`? What keeps you from changing that static content within that static array?

Comment: @NicoHaase he needs to update it dynamically

Comment: That looks strange to me - there is nothing dynamic in that code

Comment: `I have a file with a bunch of metaboxes but i'm trying to reduce the duplicate entries` 

That single metabox is repeated through the file in multiple places, I don't want to keep duplicating that in the meta_boxes[] array below. 

So want to create the single field once and update some simple fields. @NicoHaase

Comment: So are you looking for something like `eval`, in combination with `array_map`?

Comment: If you need to pull the title and populate it into the fields, use a loop to populate it.

Comment: @Aaron you have multiple metaboxes with the same title `foo`, but instead of adding an extra `foo` to the collection you want to *update* the existing one inside the array? Then you would first need to retrieve the index of the first added `foo` in order to update that one in the array

Comment: what's the point in adding a title twice into the same element?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm not sure what you mean "twice"

Comment: @Aaron `'title' => 'Metabox Example'` and `$title = 'NEW TITLE';`.

Comment: did read my question fully? I'm placing the first `$metabox` array inside the `$meta_boxes` array and am trying to update the title of the initial `$metabox` on the fly. I'm doing this because I'm going to be using this `$metabox` array multiple times and don't want to repeat the same code. @MartinZeitler

Comment: @Aaron well, I've read the question, but I don't really understand it ...nor I understand the purpose of a "meta box". ever considered using a template engine, alike Smarty or Twig (which might provide such functionality)?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sorry I can't expain it in a better way. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you could access the $title value ('name' field) like this:

```
<?php
$metabox = array(
        'name' => "initial title",
        'id'   => "column_content",
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'raw'  => false,
        'options' => array(
            'textarea_rows' => 3,
            'teeny'         => true,
            'media_buttons' => false,
        ),
    );

$metaboxFields = array();

//this is an example for 5 metaboxes.
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $metaboxFields['metabox'.$i] = $metabox;
}   


$meta_boxes = array(
    'id'         => 'page_builder', 
    'title'      => 'Metabox Example',
    'fields'     => $metaboxFields,
);

$newTitleForBox1 = 'NEW TITLE';
$meta_boxes['fields']['metabox1']["name"] = $newTitleForBox1;
```

This will access the "name" field in metabox1 in the "fields" array of the first item in the "$meta_boxes" array.

Though of course this is not a very pretty solution.

Comment: Can you explain further how that single line updates something?

Comment: Well, of course you need to declare $newTitle.
But this single line of code would replace the current value "{$title}" given to the 'name' field with the value given to the $newTitle variable.

Comment: And what should one do with that variable afterwards? How can it be used to run a replacement like given in the question?

Comment: I see I made a mistake in my answer, not setting the title like the OP asked. I changed the answer so that it should work.
Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Still, how does this **really** work? Why not read that new title from the given `meta_boxes` element? What if that should also be done for other fields, dynamically?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with "read that new title from the given meta_boxes element?".

The question is about updating the 'name' field of a 'metabox'  when the metabox is inside the meta_boxes array.

And my answer is just that, an answer to the question "a way to update the title". It is not a solution for situations with more fields or more metaboxes.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, there should be some kind of "template array" - that's why there is a value `{$title}` which should get replaced with the content of the current array's element `title`

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easy, all you need to do is add this to your code.

```
$meta_boxes[$i]['title'] = 'NEW TITLE';
```

Comment: I do understand how arrays work @DarkBee, but I still don't get why I need the [$i]. Also Would this update the title from within the array? I feel like this would update the $title outside of the meta_box[] array(), no?

Comment: Because you have multiple `metabox` in the array `metaboxes`? You'd u need to target the right `metabox` of which you want to update the title

Comment: @Aaron as far as I can see you have a multi dimensional array, that's why I added the [$i]
so here you are ordering each title of each element

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like

```
foreach ($metabox as $box){
    $box['title'] = 'yourValue';
    //here you can change the values that you want
}
```

Comment: This won't work as the default behavior of a `foreach` on an array is to copy the array